# Binding listView column dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, binding, itemtemplate

I need to create a listView in which the number of columns will be changing in runtime.

My aspx page code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ReportListView">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In ItemTemplate, I need to bind column dynamically from code behind.

My .cs page code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);

                ReportListView.DataSource = ds;
                ReportListView.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (ListViewDataItem listItem in ReportListView.Items)
    {
        PlaceHolder plc = (PlaceHolder)listItem.FindControl("itemPlaceHolder1");
        if (plc != null)
        {
                Literal ltrl = new Literal();
                ltrl.Text = "<td>" + listItem.DataItem + "</td>";
                plc.Controls.Add(ltrl);

        }
    }
```

But it return nothing on the browser. no error and no output....

Any Suggestions......

Comment: Did you check your "ds" getting filled with desired data or not?

Comment: Yes.. "ds" contains the data... but its not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after building a table with a dynamic set of columns, why not use the `GridView` and create your own `ColumnsGenerator`? Create a class that implements `IAutoFieldGenerator` which will return the set of columns to create, and assign it to the `GridView.ColumnsGenerator` property.

Should you really want to go the way of a `ListView` and templates, you could create a class that inherits `IBindableTemplate` and assign this to the `ListView.ItemTemplate`.

Comment: I need it in the listView... Can you please post some sample code on how to use IBindableTemplate class

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post on it: http://start-coding.blogspot.com/2013/06/dynamic-columns-in-listview.html.

On ItemDataBound event, do something like this (you can replace with other control, or LoadControl):

```
private void dynamicPopulateRow(HtmlTableRow row, System.Data.DataRowView drv, int iGeneration)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        // http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-enumerate-all-columns-dataviewrow-t1244448.html
        foreach (DataColumn dc in drv.Row.Table.Columns)
        {
            string sEmployeeID = drv["LoginID"].ToString();

            if (dc.ColumnName.Equals("LoginID"))
            {
                // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5daxzcy(v=vs.80).aspx
                // Define a new HtmlTableCell control.
                HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell("td");

                // Create the text for the cell.
                cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Convert.ToString(drv[dc.ColumnName])));
                cell.ColSpan = dc.ColumnName.Equals("LoginID") ? I_COLSPAN - iGeneration : 1;

                // Add the cell to the HtmlTableRow Cells collection. 
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            else if (!(dc.ColumnName.Equals("GENERATION") ||
                        dc.ColumnName.Equals("hierarchy") ||
                        dc.ColumnName.Equals("rowNo") ||
                        dc.ColumnName.Equals("EmployeeID")))
            {
                // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5daxzcy(v=vs.80).aspx
                // Define a new HtmlTableCell control.
                HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell("td");

                bool bIsNull = drv[dc.ColumnName] is System.DBNull;

                Literal ltrl = new Literal();
                ltrl.Text += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"" + dc.ColumnName + "\"" +
                                (bIsNull ? "" : " value=" + drv[dc.ColumnName].ToString()) +
                                " id=\"" + sEmployeeID + "~" + dc.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_") + "\"" +//will be retrieved later
                                " onclick=\"didModify(this)\" " +
                                (bIsNull ? " disabled" : "") +
                                (!bIsNull && ((int)drv[dc.ColumnName]) > 0 ? " checked>" : ">");

                cell.Controls.Add(ltrl);
                // Add the cell to the HtmlTableRow Cells collection. 
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            else
            {
                //other rows
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Gary, i'm interesting with your sample, but it is hard for me to understand since it looks very complex, would you simplify your code please, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void methodone()
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet()
  try
  {

  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd,con);
  sda.Fill(ds);
  ReportListView.DataSource = ds;
  ReportListView.DataBind();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
  throw;
}
finally
{
  if(con!=null)
   con.close();
}
}

//and dont foreget to call the methodone at the page load ..wherever ..
```

Comment: did you check during debug whether your ds is filled or not ? did you check your query ? is the listview control visible ?

Comment: Ha ha..remove place holders and run it on a plain form and check..may be ur messing with placeholders

Comment: yes.. 'ds' contains data... I tried removing the placeholders and got no output....

Comment: sounds strange renu :-( try with grid if u have time..i ll try n tell u morning..im leaving for the day

Comment: I tried the placeholder code within 'ItemDataBound' function of ListView control. It binds the value into listView... But however the Column name is not binded to it...